# Display local notifications when the app is killed - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, service, notifications, foreground-service

I'm trying to add a feature in one of my apps which allows the user to create a "Reminder" for a future date. I'm developing the app using Xamarin.Android.

I have created a ReminderBroadcastReceiver which extends from Broadcast Receiver. In the OnReceived method, I create a local notification. This works fine as long as the app is open or is active in background. But as soon as I kill the app, I stop receiving the notifications. Can someone please help me out with this?

I've been looking for the solution since 2 days on the internet but to no success. I've tried creating my own Foreground service as well but still no luck. I can't display a sticky notification to the user to keep the service active. Is there any other way? I'm pretty sure there should be something since other apps do it without showing notifications for keeping the service active.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to restart the phone, because once you stop debugging on Visual studio, it kills the app's capability to respond push notifications